# Tensor flow Getting started

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

Ok i'm trying to get my head around TensorFlow so downloaded their Getting started example and it works but the result was nothing to write home about so figured that the perfect place to start was to improve the accuracy by increasing the number of training cases from 6 to 60

except now its incapable of resolving the value

the original code

```
  const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7], [6, 1]);
```

my modified version

```
  const d = [];
  const r = [];
  for (let x = -50; x < 10; x++) {
    const y = x * 2 - 1;
    d.push(x);
    r.push(y);
  }
  const xs = tf.tensor(d);
  const ys = tf.tensor(r);
```

i figured ok i've increased the dataset by a factor of 10 so maybe the default learning time of 250 wasn't sufficient so i increases to incrementally to 5000 and no difference every time the result is NaN, if i change the for loop to match the orginal array then the code works again

now given my understanding of AI the more training data the better so surely 60 records isn't an excessive quanity so i assume the problem lies elsewhare but i have no idea what

any suggestions would be appreciated

edit the orginal script in full

```
async function run() {
  // Create a simple model.
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));

  // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
  model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

  // Generate some synthetic data for training. (y = 2x - 1)
  const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7], [6, 1]);

  // Train the model using the data.
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 250});

  // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen.
  // Should print approximately 39.
  document.getElementById('micro-out-div').innerText =
      model.predict(tf.tensor2d([20], [1, 1])).dataSync();
}

run();
```

Comment: Since `const y = x * 2 - 1;` is linear, this might be causing an issue.
Can you add some noise to this? 
Ex: 
`const y = x * 2 - 1 + Math.random() * 0.1;`

Comment: Had no effect still outputs NaN

Comment: Sorry that it didn't help.

Comment: Regardless, writing a loop like this won't help you with training / accuracy. You really need data that has some noise / outliers in it, so the algorithm can learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spread of values [-50 , 10 ] might be causing something called a gradient Explosion. Gradient Explosion leads to a `NaN`

Read more [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/)

Might consider normalizing the values? try keeping the values between -1 to 1

You can use `tf.keras.utils.normalize` and `tf.keras.utils.standardize` to normalize it

Comment: well that definately fixed it -50 to 10 doesn't seem that explosive but i'll check out the additional reading you suggested

Comment: During back propogation, error gradients can accumulate during an update and result in very large gradients.